# How to get Postgresql backup by command in Redhat6.9?

Tags: postgresql, backup, redhat

I'm using postgresql9.2 and OS Redhat6.9; While getting backup from postgresql database backup from command line found a error. 
I'm using two command like

```
[root@clipntouch ~]# pg_dump -h localhost -U adempiere -W -F t live_3001 > database_dump_file.tar
```

or

```
[root@clipntouch ~]# pg_dump -U adempiere live_3001 | gzip > /home/database_dump_file.gz
```

Find 2 error- 
1. For first one- pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "live_3001" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "adempiere" 
2. For second one- psql.bin: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

Any best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are very clear and verbose,

**Error 1 :** After you hit enter, you had to provide the password for the DB User, the password you typed was incorrect.

**Error 2 :** You didn't specify the parameter [-W] so it didn't ask for any password. This would work if the postgres server configuration was set to TRUST for localhost but the default configuration is always set to md5 or peer.

**To solve this, all you need to do is to understand pg_dump tool.**

```
Example: pg_dump -Fc -h localhost -d adempiere -U adempiere -v -W  > file.backup
```

**Understanding Parameters**

**-h**   It corresponds to Host where the database is located

**-d**   Refers to the database you try to backup

**-U**   It referes to the database user with backup privileges

**-W**   This parameters let you type the database user password after you run the command

**-Fc**  It allows you to generate a custom format file .backup

**-v**   Verbose, It let you see the log of what is happening in the background.

You can find more information about this command in the following link:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-pgdump.html